# wordpress gutenberg alignwide and alignfull problem

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

i am playing with the new gutenberg editor of wordpress. i have enabled alignwide and alignfull on my theme (which is using materialize), and i use these css rules for them, but it doesn't work properly.
[image]

this is how the alignwide looks.

[image]

and this is how the align full looks.

these are the alignfull and wide rules in the css:
[image]

and this is how the align full css goes:
[image]

these are the css rules for the wrapping content div:
[image]

[image]

any idea why i am not getting the right visual results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, simply use the **add_theme_support( 'align-wide' )** function to the theme’s functions.php file, attached to the after_setup_theme hook, which is fired after the theme is loaded:

```html
<?php
/**
 * Registers support for Gutenberg wide images in Writy.
 */
function writy_setup() {
  add_theme_support( 'align-wide' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'writy_setup' );
```

> Note that theme support for wide images was changed from being within
>   the Gutenberg theme support array, with a wide-images bool, to the
>   above.

Comment: hi, as i said in my question i have enabled it. that means i have this code in place.

Comment: Yes, try to add this function on functions.php file and run it.. Is it working or not. @Ron

Comment: no it does not. i even if i commented my code and used your function

Comment: ok. so i have noticed gutenberg had an update. i have updated it and my code was good. also your code as well. so to everybody that runs into the same thing- update the plugin.

Comment: Hmmm... Good Job :) @Ron